# Identify users with DELETE permissions on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m new to Oracle and working on some homework covering admin privileges, etc and am unclear how to solve this question:

> Write a SQL statement to list users and roles that have the DELETE
>   privilege on all tables owned by users in your database except SYS and
>   SYSTEM.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Start with [`dba_tb_privs`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4151.htm#REFRN23282).

Answer (score 0):

The following query may help :

```
select grantee
 from 
  (
    select ( select count(1) 
               from dba_tables t 
              where owner not in ('SYSTEM','SYS') ) as count_all_tables,
           p.grantee, count(1) as count_del_privs_per_grantee
      from dba_tab_privs p
     where p.privilege = 'DELETE'
       and exists ( select * 
                      from dba_tables t 
                     where owner not in ('SYSTEM','SYS')
                       and t.owner = p.owner
                       and t.table_name = p.table_name ) 
      group by p.grantee        
   )
 where count_all_tables = count_del_privs_per_grantee;
```